# Relative line numbers in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, line-numbers

I'm pretty sure I know the answer to this one cause I've been searching everywhere, but if anyone knows he's probably on this site.

Is it possible to display line numbers that are relative to the cursor position in Visual Studio? The line where the cursor is would always be 0, the line above would be 1 as well as the line below, etc.

Perhaps there is an addin that can do that? Given that other addins like Rockscroll can modify the margins in the VS text editor.

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. The whole point of line numbers is to serve as an objective identifier of lines of code. If they were relative to your cursor's current location, they'd change *constantly*. What good would that do anyone?

Comment: I tend to agree with Cody here - what purpose do you think this would help you (or anyone else) achieve?

Comment: It's pretty useful if you use viemu.

Comment: Relax, I was asked why I wanted the feature and I answered the question. Read up on vim if you want to know why it's useful. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: This would be incredibly useful side by side with VSVim plugin. To give an example (without bragging)... If I want to navigate line that's 10 lines above my current pos I type 10k in VIM and it goes there. But I have to know the relative position of that line to do it otherwise I'm just guessing at it.  Lots of haters in the comments. Open your minds! :)

Comment: Additionally, you can delete multiple lines and copy multiple lines easier. 7dd will delete the 7 lines below your cursor. Having the lines listed relatively will easily show you what the 7th line is. Relative numbers prevent a dumb person like from me from messing up simple mental math in such situations.

Comment: Note, for those with Visual Studio 2022, this feature is now supported natively in VsVim with `:set relativenumber`.

Answer (score 44):

Since VSCode 1.6 you can set `editor.lineNumbers` with the value of `relative` in the *settings.json* file or in *File>Preferences>Settings*.

[image: Line Numbers option in VSCode settings.]

Comment: I should downvote this because OP asked about VS - not VSCode, but this is still very useful information, so have an upvote anyway!

Comment: This answer is clearly off topic. @Thomas Glaser's answer should be up there at the top.

Answer (score 33):

Seems most extensions for relative line numbers do not support Visual Studio 2022 yet.

Fortunately, if you use **VsVim**, [it supports this directly](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/pull/2571). But it needs to enabled with `:set relativenumber`.

To make it persistent, create a *.vimrc* (`%userprofile%\.vimrc`) with this content:

```
set relativenumber
```

Comment: You want to pair this setting with `set number` so that you get also the current line number as well.

Comment: Good point, I didn't know that. That's very handy!

Comment: where should one create this .vimrc file? please suggest.

Comment: In your user profile, like `C:\Users\myname\.vimrc`

Answer (score 12):

You may want to check out my [RelativeLineNumbers](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/74d68e2b-ff64-4c51-a2ed-d8b164eee858) Visual Studio 2010 extension. Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2019 and vsvim users, [Relative Number](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BrianSchmitt.RelativeNumber) will now do the job.

Note that if you had regular line numbers in Visual Studio, this will show you 2 line numbers columns by default. You can disable VS default line numbers, and `:set number` and `:set nonumber` will toggle the extension's column.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `vscode-vim`, you toggle the feature `Smart Relative Line` open in the user settings.

1. `ctrl + shift + P` and search for user settings
2. in user settings, search for smart relative line
3. toggle this option open.

This will set absolute line number in insert mode, while relative otherwise. Quiet handy.